# How to get click event in table row in react js

Tags: reactjs

I need to get the click event in table row. My code as follow.

```
const TableBody = (props) => {
const invoices = props.invoices;
const rows = [];
invoices.forEach((invoice) => {
    rows.push(<TableRow invoice={invoice} key={invoice.invoiceNo}/>);
});
return (
    <tbody>
    {rows}
    </tbody>
  );
};
```

Above I added code for table body

```
const TableRow = (props) => {
const invoice = props.invoice;
return (
    <tr>
        <DateTableData date={invoice.dueDate}/>
        <TableData value={invoice.issuer}/>
        <TableData value={invoice.invoiceNo}/>
        <DateTableData date={invoice.invoiceDate}/>
        <TableData value={formatStringWithDefaultValue(invoice.identifier, "- - -")}/>
        <td className="total-amount">{formatCurrency(invoice.totalAmount, 'SEK')}</td>
    </tr>
 );
};
```

I want to get the clicked row in order to more details of clicked item. I am not using react table. How can i add click event to table row ?

```
class InvoiceList extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-lg-9">
                    <table className=" table table-hover table-responsive-md" style={{marginTop: '1.5rem'}}>
                        <TableHead/>
                        <TableBody invoices={this.props.invoices}/>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div className="col-lg-3">
                    <InvoiceSummary/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

I tried this tutorial but that didn't help. https://material-ui.com/demos/tables/

Comment: I think it may be easier to just make one of the elements inside the table a link such as an invoice number. That is the norm for making table elements clickable.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const TableRow = (props) => {
const invoice = props.invoice;
return (
    <tr onClick={props.yourMethod}>
        <DateTableData date={invoice.dueDate}/>
        <TableData value={invoice.issuer}/>
        <TableData value={invoice.invoiceNo}/>
        <DateTableData date={invoice.invoiceDate}/>
        <TableData value={formatStringWithDefaultValue(invoice.identifier, "- - -")}/>
        <td className="total-amount">{formatCurrency(invoice.totalAmount, 'SEK')}</td>
    </tr>
 );
};
```